# NodeJS: How to re-display custom CLI menu after executing corresponding functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I come from a low-level programming background, so JS and NodeJS are a new realm for me.

I am trying to create an application that begins by displaying a CLI menu to the user. Upon the user selecting a menu option, a corresponding functionality will be carried out. Once that functionality completes, I want the menu to be re-displayed.

A very simple way of handling this in Python and embedded C is to enclose the menu in a while(1) loop and then terminate the program/script process when the user selects the corresponding menu option. However, in NodeJS, you cannot run a menu in a while(1) loop -- the functions called corresponding to each menu option never actually get called and the menu simply re-displays immediately.

In other words, what is the NodeJS equivalent of:

```
while(1) {
  displayMenuToUser();
  // Wait for user to select which menu option they want
  if (quitMenuOptionSelectedByUser) {
    terminateProcess();
  } else {
    executeFunctionCorrespondingToTheSelectedMenuOption();
    // At this point the menu should be re-displayed so the user can select another option
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Inquirer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer)

I made this example which keeps looping if you answer **yes** on the `Go again?` question:

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');

const showMenu = () => {
    inquirer
    .prompt([{
        name: 'age',
        type: 'input',
        message: 'What\'s your age?',
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        type: 'list',
        message: 'Where do you live?',
        choices: ['USA', 'China', 'Germany', 'France'],
    }, {
        name: 'back',
        type: 'input',
        message: 'Go again?',
        choices: ['yes', 'no'],
    }]
    ).then((answers) => {
        console.log(`\nMy age is ${answers.age} and I live in ${answers.country}.\n`);
        if (answers.back === 'yes') {
            return showMenu();
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

showMenu();
```